# CSS menu center positioning

Tags: html, css

I am learning html/css. I want to ask a dumb question. I have positioned my header

```
#header { 
    margin: 0% auto; 
    text-align: left; 
    width: 1280px; 
}
```

it is in the centre,
now I want to position a sub-menu which is a bit shorter than header and is going also to be in the center, but I can't. Please help me to improve my skills. Thanks in advance!

Comment: see my answer and let me know ia any issues or i am lagging some where.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly this is what you should do.

On the html side I would create a  header that wraps up both your header and your sub-menu.  This so as to center everything.  You will end up with the following

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="header">

    </div>

    <div id="submenu">

    </div>
</div>
```

on the css side you would do the same as you did with the header but this time you would apply the centering strategy to all the 3 div tags.  This will first center the container then center the inner elements within the container itself.  This would be the CSS you might end up with.

```
#container { 
    margin: 0% auto;  
}

#header { 
    margin: 0% auto; 
    text-align: left; 
    width: 1280px; 
} 
#submenu { 
    margin: 0% auto; 
}
```

This is the naive way of how to implement what you'd want.  A more elegant solution would involve the use of classes.  It will save you some time writing repeated css and can be reused over and over. Ultimately using classes this is what you would end up with

```
    <div id="container" class="center">
        <div id="header" class="center">

        </div>

        <div id="submenu" class="center">

        </div>
    </div>

.center { 
    margin: 0% auto;  
}

#header { 
    text-align: left; 
    width: 1280px; 
}
```

Hope this helps.

Also http://www.w3schools.com/ is a resource

Comment: thanks, but it brings to the left my sub menu, do you have any other tips? yeah, sub menu is shorter than header and it is situated on the bottom of header... :)

Comment: Hmm strange.  Could you post exactly what you have done so far?  I would be able to see what is wrong

Comment: thank you bro, thanks everyone, for help, i have already done it :)

Answer (score 1):

see the fiddle

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uyECX/3/

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/uyECX/3/embedded/result/